# django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse some characters: |{{b.count}}||rangef

Tags: python, html, django, error-handling, range

I'm trying to loop in a Django template by using a custom filter, but for some reason I receive this error:

> django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse some characters: |{{b.count}}||rangef

**myfilters.py**

```
@register.filter(name='rangef')
def rangef(number):
    return range(number)
```

**index.html**

```
<div class="container">
{% for i in {{b.count}}|rangef %}
    <p>Some text</p>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

> Important to mention that **b.count** is an **Integer field**.
> Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

The [custom filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) can be used with the following syntax:

```
{{ b.count | rangef }}
```

Note that the filter part is inside the curly braces since this will apply the filter `rangef` to the value on the left, `b.count`.

Note that filters are not supported within `for` loops. Consider changing your model so that it exposes the filtered value directly, e.g.

```
def b_range(self):
    return range(self.b.count)
```

```
{% for i in b_range %}
…
{% endfor %}
```